# Mini Wiki In Website Design?

Tags: css, xhtml, html

I am designing a website, and am going to be implementing a sort of say "Wiki". I am not doing a script, none of that, it's going to be pure XHTML and CSS.

What I want to know from the StackOverflow community, is how I should approach this scenario. 
I want to be able to pull out an external stylesheet, in which is lightweight, while maintaining the style sheet for the overall design (because, like I said, it's being implemented).

So instead of basically copying and pasting the style sheet used from the entire design, I want to be able to call and external style sheet, in which I can call for the specific divs used in the Mini Wiki. 
I want to know how I can call that said style sheet, before the divs that are going to be called in the HTML document, so the following divs can have the custom styles applied through the specified external style sheet for the Mini Wiki.

Is that possible? Is it possible to call an external style sheet in a div, allowing the styles to override the default style sheet of the page? I am confused and would love some help. I want some feedback and some ideas.

Comment: Hello Aaron. Could you post some of the HTML / CSS you've tried so far? - it might help explain the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this isn't possible.

A stylesheet can only be applied to an entire document.

You can limit a rule-set to a section of the document by using a [descendant combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#descendant-combinators).